# iBeacon: How to write an integration test case for iBeacon

Tags: ios, testing, ibeacon

I'm writing an integration test case for an iPhone App. The app has iBeacon features.

I don't have enough experience to work with iBeacon but I think I need to check some special points or conditions. Take the background mode, for example, I may have to exam the point.

Does anyone know any useful example, or references for writing the test case?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think that my question is off-topic. I believe some engineers have the same issue. Stackoverflow is for engineers, right?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail exactly what kind of tests you want to write (executable or manual) and exactly what kind of things you want to test?